# firewalld is not working in CentOS 8: no rule at all is created in iptables

Tags: centos, iptables, firewalld, centos8

I've recently upgraded a clean install CentOS 7 to CentOS 8 using this tutorial:

https://www.tecmint.com/upgrade-centos-7-to-centos-8/

I had no extra software installed, only the base install. After upgrading, the first thing I tried to do was to open doors only to SSH and HTTP, so I enabled and start firewalld:

```sh
systemctl enable firewalld
systemctl start firewalld
systemctl status firewalld
● firewalld.service - firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/firewalld.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2019-12-24 11:05:50 -02; 10min ago
     Docs: man:firewalld(1)
 Main PID: 7620 (firewalld)
    Tasks: 2 (limit: 17886)
   Memory: 22.1M
   CGroup: /system.slice/firewalld.service
           └─7620 /usr/libexec/platform-python -s /usr/sbin/firewalld --nofork --nopid

dez 24 11:05:49 renie.cc systemd[1]: Stopped firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon.
dez 24 11:05:49 renie.cc systemd[1]: Starting firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon...
dez 24 11:05:50 renie.cc systemd[1]: Started firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon.
```

Then added ssh and http services:

```sh
firewall-cmd --add-service http
firewall-cmd --add-service http --permanent
firewall-cmd --add-service ssh
firewall-cmd --add-service ssh --permanent
firewall-cmd --add-service ssh
firewall-cmd --list-all
public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: eth0
  sources: 
  services: http ssh
  ports: 
  protocols: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```

But I see no rule at all in IPTables:

```sh
iptables -nvL
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 143 packets, 13998 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 114 packets, 13295 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Even after rebooting the server, no rules are created. Could this be caused by the CentOS 7 → CentOS 8 upgrade?

I did not tested or used firewalld before upgrading this server, but I have others CentOS 7 servers which have working firewalld.

Is there any log I can analyse in order to debug the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: firewalld is not using iptables; check firewall-cmd --list-ports ; add specific port instead of service if something is wrong

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because you don't see any *iptables* rule, doesn't mean *firewalld* is not working. Actually *firewalld* switched to using [*nftables*](https://wiki.nftables.org/) as backend. So you can find your rules with for example:

```
nft list ruleset
```

The rules you added for *ssh* and *http* would likely be in the chain `filter_IN_public_allow`:

```
        chain filter_IN_public_allow {
                tcp dport ssh ct state new,untracked accept
                tcp dport http ct state new,untracked accept
        }
```

You will probably *also* find empty *iptables* rules (but seen as *nftables* rules) in the output of `nft list ruleset`, because *iptables* is using the *nftables* compatibility kernel API:

```
# iptables -V
iptables v1.8.2 (nf_tables)
```

useful link: [Redhat - Firewalld: The Future is nftables](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2018/08/10/firewalld-the-future-is-nftables/)