# Translating a firewall-cmd command to iptables command

Tags: centos, iptables, firewall, firewalld

I read [here](https://www.unixmen.com/iptables-vs-firewalld/) that `iptables` package is part of the Linux Kernel and that every GUI firewall tools are in the end translated in some kind of `iptable` rules.

Now I am setting up Centos 8 server folowing [this](https://linuxconfig.org/installing-apache-on-linux-redhat-8) guide which sets up firewall settings using these lines:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --add-service=http
sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```

Prior to this I could not visit my index page `/var/www/html/index.html` using `http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/index.html` in my browser. But after this I could visit the site.

I was surprised that there was nothing appended to any of the three chains  inside `iptables` table. In other words table was completely empty:

```
[ziga@localhost ~]$ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination  

[ziga@localhost ~]$ sudo iptables -S
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

It looks like `firewall-cmd` is doing something I don't understand and I want to avoid this. Is there a way to achieve exactly the same result that `firewall-cmd` by only using `iptable` commands?

Comment: Isn't firewalld directly "talking" to netfilter, just like iptables?

Comment: @Lenniey You are right! So how would I achieve same thing with `iptables`?

Comment: And the iptables policy on the INPUT chain is ACCEPT so *all* traffic should go though it. Can you get the output from `iptables -S` ?

Comment: If you want to switch to using iptables (I've been using it for years and I find it way easier than firewalld!) there's a pretty good tutorial here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-migrate-from-firewalld-to-iptables-on-centos-7

Comment: @sensadrome I added the output of `iptables -S`.

Comment: The reason of your empty rules is explained there: [firewalld is not working in CentOS 8: no rule at all is created in iptables](https://serverfault.com/questions/996664/firewalld-is-not-working-in-centos-8-no-rule-at-all-is-created-in-iptables/) . So either use the generated nftables rules instead, or train in using directly iptables commands (but the focus is shifting slowly to nftables now, so this might be time not well spent).